# Is the RTL8169 PCI Gigabit Ethernet Controller supported?

Tags: networking, drivers, ethernet

I wanted two network cards in my SFF PC, so bought a cheap one from Ebay.  I plugged the card in, and hoped that it would 'just work' - no such luck.

It was detected at boot time - the following lines from dmesg :

```
[    0.134880] pci 0000:10:00.0: [10ec:8169] type 00 class 0x020000
[    0.134901] pci 0000:10:00.0: reg 0x10: [io  0x1100-0x11ff]
[    0.134909] pci 0000:10:00.0: reg 0x14: [mem 0xf0600000-0xf06000ff]
[    0.134945] pci 0000:10:00.0: reg 0x30: [mem 0x00000000-0x0001ffff pref]
[    0.134965] pci 0000:10:00.0: supports D1 D2
[    0.134967] pci 0000:10:00.0: PME# supported from D1 D2 D3hot D3cold
```

...

```
[    1.438417] r8169 Gigabit Ethernet driver 2.3LK-NAPI loaded
[    1.438527] r8169 0000:10:00.0 (unnamed net_device) (uninitialized): not PCI Express
[    1.438785] r8169 0000:10:00.0 eth0: RTL8169sb/8110sb at 0xffffc90001bac000, 00:e0:4c:44:07:a1, XID 10000000 IRQ 20
[    1.438787] r8169 0000:10:00.0 eth0: jumbo features [frames: 7152 bytes, tx checksumming: ok]
[    1.475447] r8169 0000:10:00.0 enp16s0: renamed from eth0
```

It is listed as "DISABLED" by lshw :

```
*-network DISABLED
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8169 PCI Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:10:00.0
   logical name: enp16s0
   version: 10
   serial: 00:e0:4c:44:07:a1
   size: 10Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 66MHz
   capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half latency=32 link=no maxlatency=64 mingnt=32 multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
   resources: irq:20 ioport:1100(size=256) memory:f0600000-f06000ff memory:f0620000-f063ffff
```

And it is not listed in the output of ifconfig... The output from lsmod includes:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
r8169                  81920  0
```

Is this card supported by (Ubuntu 16.10) Linux?  If so, what hoop do I need to jump through to get it recognised (i.e. listed when I run ifconfig)?

Answer (score 3):

It's well known that the r8169 driver is flawed. This is a fix for that, but I don't know if it'll solve your problem... until we try. Lets install the driver that works...

## In the terminal application...

Type the following commands, one at a time:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install dkms
sudo apt-get install r8168-dkms
sudo ifconfig enp16s0 up
```

Then reboot your computer.

If that doesn't fix the problem, check that you've got a good CAT6 ethernet cable. You should probably see a blinking green or yellow LED near where the cable plugs into the card. If you need to troubleshoot further, plug a new/different ethernet cable directly from the new ethernet card, **directly** to the router or dsl/cable modem (bypassing all other wiring and switches/hubs).

Comment: The r8168-dkms driver, installed as above, seems to have made no difference.  The RTL8169 device is still "DISABLED" in lshw and enp16s0 is still not listed by ifconfig.

Comment: And you have `Enable Networking` checkmarked in the Network panel icon? What happened with the blinking LED and the cable test?

Comment: This is on Ubuntu Server - so I don't have a network panel.  Is there an equivalent setting accessible from the command line?  The LED blinks when I plug in a network cable... I don't think the problem is faulty hardware.  The on-board Ethernet (eth0) works fine - only the Realtek card (the second Ethernet adaptor) is marked as 'Disabled' according to lshw - and absent according to ifconfig.

Comment: What confuses me is that the card says `link=no` and `speed=10Mbit/s`. I'd really like to do the cable test directly to your router/modem... and using a different CAT6 cable. If that test doesn't give us a clue, we may have to wait for a server guru to chime in.

Comment: There was no cable plugged into the Realtek adaptor when I captured the output from lshw.

Comment: Well, it makes sense to put up correct information if you want a more correct diagnosis. I wonder if the lshw changes with a cable plugged in? And I'll ask again, for the last time... cable test, cable test, cable test.

Comment: The information in the post is accurate. My problem is that enp16s0  is not presented as a device by ifconfig. N.B. eth0 is presented - irrespective what cables are connected.  I expect to be able to configure the static IP for enp16s0  before plugging it into other network hardware.

Comment: Maybe you have to do something like `sudo ifup enp16s0` or `sudo ifconfig enp16s0 up`?

Comment: Many thanks!!!  It was as simple as requiring "ifconfig enp15s0 up" - I'd wrongly assumed that ifconfig would report the device even if it was not "up".

Comment: Glad you got it going!

Comment: I had to edit my /etc/network/interfaces to refer to enp16s0 instead of eth1, and I had to adjust my iptables to refer to enp16s0 instead of eth1 and all is working.